# netstat shows inequal amount of mutual connection between two hosts

Tags: networking, linux-networking, connection, handle-leak

I'm trying to investigate why the amounts of connections between two physical hosts `10.240.48.9` и `10.241.169.7` (`CentOS 6`) don't match each other (diagnosed from the each one respectively):

On `10.241.169.7`:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnpa | grep tcp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 10.240.48.9 | wc -l

54
```

On `10.240.48.9`:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnpa | grep tcp | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 10.241.169.7 | wc -l

189
```

Why is it possible at all? I guess there is a connection leak on the side of `10.240.48.9`, but how to find out which software is leaking?

Comment: I too often use `wc -l` and then have to step back and compare the output directly to identify the problem - so how do these 54 compared to the 189 lines do look like. They should carry all relevant info like process name etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the output without the `wc -l`.  The pattern '10.241.169.7' matches 11 addresses.  You may want a pattern like `^tcp.*10.241.169.7:.*ESTABLISED` which reduces the number of commands required.

You don't need `sudo` nor all the netstat options. Try a command like:

```
netstat -nt | grep `^tcp.*10.241.169.7:.*ESTABLISED` | wc -l
```